# 07 Camry front wheel bearing damage so quickly

Tags: wheel-bearing, cv-joint, nut, rod

I have replaced the the right front wheel cv joint with after market one made by a Taiwanese spare part manufacturer.
When the mechanic install the cv joint in the rod, after 3 or 5 days, sound of the front bearing came. I checked, I found the cv joint 32 nut was loose!!
I tighten the nut, but the bearing is damaged.
I replaced the bearing, and after 3 or 4 days same thing happened.
Nut was loose, new bearing is damaged.

What could be the cause of this?
CV joint it self
Or it's installation in the rod?
Or the nut
Or something else?

Comment: Was a new nut used? They usually have a locking mechanism.

Comment: I used the new nut

Comment: It come with the new cv joint

Comment: How tight did you do it up? Was it properly fitted?

Comment: Very tight, I extended the wrench to increase the torque.